# Is it a good idea to use HTML5 now?

Tags: html

I know it will be 'finalized/made official' in 2012 (and something to do with it being given 'Recommendation status' in 2022), but I'm wondering if it's a good idea to make a site using HTML5 now.

A simple portfolio sorta site? Given that most users (most people using IE) won't have support for it, although IE9 (*shock*) will be shipping with support.

Comment: Ah, now you see, if I say a specific part, there's bound to be a browser out there that doesn't support that current feature.

Comment: Bottom line is, jumping into it now, you're an early adopter. Some may claim otherwise but the truth is that these committees work **very** slow and they need the backing of a large number of competitive browser vendors. Why take on the risk for a fraction of the features you want when you can use Silverlight or Flash/Flex and develop on a mature, backwards compatible platform now?

Comment: @Crusader: HTML5 is fairly stable; what's left is basically minor issues. Most of the draft is unlikely to change, at least not significantly (which is why it is already being implemented by many vendors). The fact that W3C is an extremely slow beureaucratic organization has very little to do with anything — CSS2.1 wasn't made a recommendation until 2007, and by then it had been used and implemented for several years.

Comment: So, the vibe I'm basically getting is....no?

Comment: @You You're making broad assumptions regarding future browsers as well as a number of other shortcomings which it does nothing to address, some of which have been elaborated on down below, but okay. I love pissing off HTML5 evangelists. :) Sorry, but HTML5 is mostly hype right now. We'll see where it stands a few years from now.

Comment: @Crusader: good for you, but I'd keep the trolling off SO. This is a Q&A site, not an imageboard. Regarding assumptions on future browsers; it's pretty much given that all major browsers will support large parts of HTML5 within a few years, since non-IE browsers are almost there already and Microsoft has promised support in IE9. And I'll bet it'll run more smoothly than Flash on Linux, too.

Comment: It's not trolling, it's just stating opinions--some of which are the same as Gartner researchers--and I find it hiliarous when some people react so defensively. HTML5 is mostly hype now. How certain are you that "support" translates to a complete lack of differences? You can't be certain, so there's still a risk, it's that simple.

Comment: Of course "support" isn't *guaranteed* to mean complete lack of differences (case in point: IE), that's bound to happen when several different vendors implement a standard. But hey, at least I have choice. (And there's not a complete lack of differences in Flash either; the Linux port of Flash is horrible compared to the Windows version, for example.)

Comment: Flash doesn't solve the cross platform issue 100% (although I suspect part of that is lack of cooperation from those user communities), but my main point is that it DOES solve the issue of cross browser differences--a much more common and annoying issue.

Comment: Silverlight and Flash/Flex don't run on the most interesting part of the market (that where people are spending lots of money): iPhone/iPad.

Comment: True, Apple's closed/proprietary operating system is intentionally crippled in this way. But you really think that'll last long with an open OS alternative like ALL the various droid phones out there? Apple is one company with some good marketing--against the **entire** mobile market, the odds are against them over time.

Comment: Update - actually allegedly Android overtook iOS in market share, so I've heard. So intentionally crippled iJunk isn't so much the "most interesting" anymore, I guess. I don't know why HTML5ers always run to the mobile OS debate though. Desktop is still the primary market for making money, and it's most certainly the primary platform for business applications, which is where a VM-based Silverlight/Flex/JavaFX strategy really does great.

Comment: This is a really late comment, but I'd like to point out the fact that Silverlight is all but dead now, but sadly HTML5 still isn't fully ratified.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no one monolithic HTML5. HTML5 is being developed as a single large (oh so very large) document, yes, but that doesn't reflect reality(*).

That is to say, HTML5 is a collection of loosely related incremental improvements to HTML4. Some of those new features are widely implemented already. Some of them you can safely use knowing that they'll degrade usefully for old browsers. Some of them you can use as long as you add explicit fallback code. Some of them will be shutting out some browsers for the foreseeable future. Some of them will only ever have minority support. Some of them may never be implemented at all, or may yet be edited out of the standard. And many new features that are often regarded as being “HTML5” aren't in HTML5 at all, but other standards (CSS3, ECMA262-5, DOM extensions, WebSocket...).

You will have to pick and choose which the features of the New Web you want individually, judging by current and apparent future support. There's not a switch for ‘using’ vs ‘not using’ HTML5, other than merely the doctype itself (which doesn't get you any new behaviour).

*: This was a big mistake, in my opinion. It would have been better to quickly standardise the bits that were already supported by everyone—like HTML3.2 did after the HTML3.0 fiasco (XHTML2, anyone?)—and then add new features in a more modular fashion. But that's not what happened, and it's too late to do much about it now.

Comment: No disagreement here, but personally I can't see why you'd want to remain subjected to such a rapidly evolving, chaotic, and non-standard environment when we have **consistent** platforms like Silverlight and Flex/Flash with which to build once and not have to worry about future compatibility problems.  HTML5 needs to unify a historically competitive and non-cooperative group (browser vendors) when what we probably should be doing is using virtualization technologies to give developers standardized, stable development platforms to work within. Standardized plugin platforms fit the bill.

Comment: I just wish the OSS community could develop an "OSS Flash" (and have it not fragment into 10 different incompatible branches) so people stop complaining about proprietary control over platforms that are freely given away.

Comment: @Crusader: Silverlight and Flash is consistent? You must be in a dreamworld somewhere.

Comment: @Lie They're much, **much** more consistent than 5 different browsers running on 3 very different operating systems. They're the only consistent platforms available on the Internet (well, Java). Write an app to Flash and you'll never have to rewrite it again--THAT is the point.

Comment: @Crusader: really? I have only seen Flash/Java applets that run on Windows crashing the browser in Linux or vice versa, or taking gigantic amount of unwarranted memory. Faulty Javascript/HTML may cause the page to show incorrectly, but at least it doesn't crash the browser.

Comment: Yes, Java destroys my browser on Ubuntu.

Comment: One man's consistent is another man's stagnant, I suppose! ;-) And yeah, personally I'm not a fan of plugins. I'm glad applets and media-player embedding are dying, replaced by Flash, and I'm glad HTML5 `<video>` is starting to muscle in on Flash video. The “OSS Flash” in terms of the vector animation Flash was originally designed for is arguably SVG plus scripting, but we've got a way to go yet on support and speed (IE9 is doing great work here) and authoring tools.

Comment: WOW now thats what I call an answer!

Comment: Why assume this is a Flash problem and not an issue with the browser/OS? It could be either. Most problems with Flash tend to be poor support from things wrapped around it or interacting with it. Now at least I see where you're coming from. Perhaps Adobe needs Linux people to actually report such issues (if they are indeed widespread) rather than simply complain about them not getting fixed? They can only do so much with in-house testing.

Comment: For what it's worth, the new Flash Player Square beta on Ubuntu has been by far the most stable Flash I've ever used on any platform. Which isn't saying a great deal, but still. Also Flash is often affected by, and receives the blame for, bugs in graphics card video acceleration drivers.

Comment: That's good to hear, and I expect that by 2022 (when HTML5 might be 'complete'), cross platform issues should be gone. If not, I'll be glad to dump any inferior platform for a stable, consistent one.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to prepare your website for HTML5, but **please** be backwards compatible to allow users with a browser that is not yet "ready" for HTML5 to be able to view your site, event if that means limited functionality. That way, users with the latest browsers will reap full benefits, but those of us who are not on the bleeding edge will still be able to view content. As you can see, I feel somewhat strongly about this topic, but hey, I'm a realist.

Also, keep in mind that there are technologies like Silverlight and Flash, today, that can support rich functionality, if you want to allows non-HTML5 compatible browsers to also view such content.

Comment: +1, it will be a gradual shift so keep older browsers on hand for testing -- but you do indeed want to be ready

Comment: True say, I know there are workarounds for IE.. but I'm wondering is it worth the hassle just yet-- just more coding isn't it?

Comment: It's NOT worth the hassle yet. Trust me, you will not like having to fix bugs and issues that **will** arise eventually when some browser (or new version of a browser) breaks something. Browser vendors haven't been able to cooperate in the past, and that was only with two major competitors, so there's no reason to believe that even more competitors controlled by very different groups can cooperate in the future. HTML5 is a gamble.

Comment: http://www.modernizr.com/ << This is quite cool, found it just now. If anyone does decide to use HTML5 use this.. It does most of what you've said above ^^.

Comment: That brings up another of my complaints with the HTML5 deal - a very fragmented and rapidly changing set of dev libraries, tools, and so on. I do some amount of research on all these "JavaScript frameworks" (for lack of better terms) and I've yet to see that one. At least if you hire a Silverlight or a Flex developer, you *know* they've used the same exact APIs you're using.

Comment: I see your point, but neither Flex nor Silverlight provide native support for Linux... and I hate sites that tell me to download Silverlight to view.

Comment: As I've said, **perfect** cross platform support is in the future on all fronts (RIA and HTML5), but on the Flex/Flash front you're at least partially incorrect: http://www.howtoforge.com/native_linux_flash_player9_in_ubuntu  I do understand that even a one-time-process like this is a pain to have to do at all, but I attribute this to the Linux ecosystem more than anything else. It's been awhile since I've used Linux but if installs are still a *fraction* of how painful they used to be, it's not yet worth the hassle when Winblows can install stuff like this with one click (or already has it).

Answer (score 1):

Certain bits of HTML5, sure. Almost all new elements introduced in HTML5 can be used already, thanks to the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), and if you provide a suitable fallback you could be using `<video>` and `<audio>` as well. Those, along with the more advanced scripting features (local storage, etc.) are the features that will take time to implement.

Also, while Mark Pilgrim's [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) mostly discusses features that won't be available for some time (at least not in IE, i.e. the majority of web users), the [chapter on semantics](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html) is both interesting and applicable.

Also keep in mind what your target audience is; if most of your visitors are from the designer community (or whatever), most of them probably have a browser with HTML5 capabilities. WebKit browsers [already support much of the HTML5 draft](http://rakaz.nl/2010/03/the-html5-test.html).

Comment: Yeah, it's more sitepoint.com than 4chan.org (please dont hurt me)

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on their downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you should understand is that html5 is not ONE big thing, it is a lot of bits and parts that you will start to use envtually here is a extract from [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

> 1. It’s not one big thing
>
> You may well ask: “How can I start
>   using HTML5 if older browsers don’t
>   support it?” But the question itself
>   is misleading. HTML5 is not one big
>   thing; it is a collection of
>   individual features. So you can’t
>   detect “HTML5 support,” because that
>   doesn’t make any sense. But you can
>   detect support for individual
>   features, like canvas, video, or
>   geolocation.
>
> You may think of HTML as tags and
>   angle brackets. That’s an important
>   part of it, but it’s not the whole
>   story. The HTML5 specification also
>   defines how those angle brackets
>   interact with JavaScript, through the
>   Document Object Model (DOM). HTML5
>   doesn’t just define a  tag;
>   there is also a corresponding DOM API
>   for video objects in the DOM. You can
>   use this API to detect support for
>   different video formats, play a video,
>   pause, mute audio, track how much of
>   the video has been downloaded, and
>   everything else you need to build a
>   rich user experience around the
>    tag itself.

If you are really interested you will find [this](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

There are people that wanna be progressive, those are the ones that bring the change, and I figure your one of them. So my advice would be, sure, cool, use it, just with care that users whose browsers don't support it also have decent experience.

Things that might help:
http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

("Public repo for the latest HTML5 JavaScript shiv for IE to recognise and style the HTML5 elements. ")

Also, as new user i can't post more than one link, but look for css3pie:

("PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.")

Answer (score 1):

Once IE 9 is released, all major browsers vendors will support a large subset of HTML5. http://caniuse.com is a very useful site for answering the question "Which HTML5 related feature can I use now (or in the near future)?"

**Updated** (to address @Crusader's comment):

By some measures the market share of browsers without at least some HTML5 support (i.e. IE 6,7,8) is now lower than 50%. In other words, the era of HTML5 has already arrived.

With the arrival of IE 9 soon, I predict the share of browsers with no-HTML5 support will fall to less than 25% in the next 12 months. And for those who refuse to upgrade (or can't because of corporate policy), [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) allows easy use of HTML5 in IE 6,7, and 8 for sites that need to support those browsers.

Or consider: the only reason MS is implementing HTML5 features in IE 9 (instead of continuing to put all its eggs in the Silverlight basket) is because they know HTML5 has already arrived and they are late to the party.

Comment: But, meanwhile, look at how many people are still using less than IE 8. It'll still be awhile until decent support is common, even after IE 9--and it's yet to be seen how well 9 will perform. It could be "a Vista" or "an ME", for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that html5 is a blanket term.  Using the doctype is just the start.  I wouldn't start including advanced webkit animations in all your sites, but using border-radius and box-shadow will work with most(minus ie) browsers and degrade gracefully.

Comment: But how can we say such features "work" if 50%+ of Internet users use IE where it doesn't exactly work?  Do you mean to say these "work" or "won't completely break the page"?

Comment: i mean work, and I excluded ie. please read before flaming

Comment: Wasn't a flame, just asking the question. :) It's just that to me for it to "work" IE has to support it, and it sounds like you excluded it because it lacks support, right?

Comment: @crusader "will work with most(minus ie) browsers"

Comment: You know what, I did slightly misread that initially - apologies.

Comment: border-radius and box-shadow have nothing whatsoever to do with HTML5. They're part of CSS3. People really need to stop lumping CSS3 in with HTML5, they're completely separate.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, this was pointed out in another answer but we didn't connect that fact here.